# Where clause with numpy with single array and / or empty_like

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to figure out how the np.where clause works. I create a simple df:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(3, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df)

   A  B  C  D
0  5  8  9  5
1  0  0  1  7
2  6  9  2  4
```

Now when I implement:

```
print(np.where(df.values, 1, np.nan))
```

I receive:

```
[[  1.   1.   1.   1.]
 [ nan  nan   1.   1.]
 [  1.   1.   1.   1.]]
```

But when I create an empty_like array from df: and put it into where clause I receive this:

```
print(np.where(np.empty_like(df.values), 1, np.nan))

[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

Really could use help on explaining how where clause works on a single array.

Comment: Why are you using `np.empty_like`? Note that its values will not be `0`, and thus none of them will be falsey, which is why `np.where` returns an ndarray of ones

Comment: Hello @yatu The empty_like actually produces values of zero but the result is all nan unlike OP's. can't reproduce the problem

Comment: empty_like creates an array of **abritrary** data. So yes some of the of the time none of it is 0.

Comment: **np.empty_like** was in one case I've found on the Internet for my problem, but then realized that without it it works fine, so how to read the first implementation like **np.where(array, 1, np.nan)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**np.empty_like()**

**Docs:-**

numpy.empty_like(prototype, dtype=None, order='K', subok=True)

Return a new array with the same shape and type as a given array.

```
>>> a = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6])                         # a is array-like
>>> np.empty_like(a)
array([[-1073741821, -1073741821,           3],    #random
       [          0,           0, -1073741821]])
```

np.empty_like() creates an array of the **same shape and type** as the given array but **with random numbers**. This array now goes into np.where()

**numpy.where()**

**Docs:-**

numpy.where(condition[, x, y])

Return elements that are chosen from x or y depending on condition.

Example:-

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> np.where(a < 5, a, 10*a)
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
>>>np.where(a,1,np.nan)
array([nan,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

In Python any number other than zero is considered to be **TRUE** whereas zero is considered to **FALSE**.

When **np.where()** gets a np.array it checks for the condition, Here the array itself acts as condition i.e, the np.where evaluates to **TRUE** when the array elements are not zero and **FALSE** when they are 0. So the "True" elements are replaced by **1** and "False" elements by **np.nan**.

Reference:-

1. [numpy.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)
2. [numpy.empty_like()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty_like.html)

Comment: _"... any number other than zero is considered to be TRUE whereas zero is considered to FALSE."_ - that is what I was missing, great !